# Desabilitar botão de submit após validar campo vazio usando jquery

Tags: jquery

Quero desabilitar o botão de submit para validar alguns campos impedindo que estejam em branco. Porém tem uma pegadinha, pois esses campos somente são exibidos de acordo com a seleção de um combo.

Ex.:
Combo qtd de empregados (1 a 5)
Selecionando 1, exibe a div contendo os campos Nome Funcionário 1 e CPF 1
Selecionando 2, exibe a div com os campos de funcionários 1 e 2.
Assim por diante.

Então não adianta eu colocar um required, pois se o usuário selecionar 1 os campos Nome Funcionário 5 e CPF 5 não são necessários.

Obrigada!

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/callbacks.disable/ acho que é isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### O jeito mais facil é setar o `disabled`

```
$('botao_submit').attr('disabled', true);
```

Mais informações:

1. [$.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)
2. [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/disabled)

### Segue um exemplo mais detalhado (jeito mais complicado)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  //troque o click por submit e o btEnvio por form, coloquei assim com click por que provavelmente o SO bloqueia o submit, e nao funciova o codigo, mas com o click consegue basicamente o mesmo efeito
  //$('#form').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#btEnvio').on('click', function(e) {
    var tudoCerto = funcao_que_valida_se_esta_tudo_de_acordo_com_o_que_voce_precisa();
    if (tudoCerto) {
      //pode processar alguma coisinha que precisar aqui, mas o form vai ser enviado logo em seguida
      return true;
    } else {

      //esse return false vai inpedir que o formulario seja enviado, basicamente bloqueia/para o submit
      //logo é um bom lugar para colocar um alert aou qualquer outra coisa que quiser
      alert('Selecione a quantidade de funcionarios');
      return false;
    }
  });

  function funcao_que_valida_se_esta_tudo_de_acordo_com_o_que_voce_precisa() {
    var qtdFunc = parseInt($('#qtdFuncionarios').val());
    return qtdFunc > 0;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form" action="http://blablabla.com.br">
  <select id="qtdFuncionarios">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
  <div>
    <!-- aqui vao os dados para o numeor de funcionarios selecionados no select -->
  </div>

  <button id="btEnvio" type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Não sei como fazer isso para ele validar pela quantidade informada no combo.

Comment: @mmooser da uma olhada de novo, adicionei umas coisinhas na resposta